# UIPrintInteractionController printing much slower than through Canon App

Tags: ios, swift, printing

Does anyone have any idea why printing via UIPrintInteractionController in swift is so much slower than printing via the iOS Canon Print app?

Also printing via the iOS photo app takes several minutes to start printing.

I've testet a 100x148mm image with 300 ppi.